# Populate selected values using select2 multiple select

Tags: javascript, jquery, onload, jquery-select2

I have a select2 to select multiple options from a dropdown, i also have it selecting multiple options. Is there anyway of populating the input field with values that are selected on page load by changing its value in some way, so when the page is loaded there are options already selected.

part of my code as follows:

```
 $('#fruitSelect').select2({
            multiple: true,
            placeholder: "Select fruits...",
            data: FRUIT_GROUPS,
            query: function (options) {
                var selectedIds = options.element.select2('val');
                var data = jQuery.extend(true, {}, FRUIT_GROUPS);
                var selectableGroups = $.map(data, function (group) {
                    var areAllChildrenSelected = true,
                        parentMatchTerm = false,
                        anyChildMatchTerm = false;
                    if (group.text.toLowerCase().indexOf(options.term.toLowerCase()) >= 0) {
                        parentMatchTerm = true;
                    }
                    var i = group.children.length
                    while (i--) {
                        var child = group.children[i];

                        if (selectedIds.indexOf(child.id) < 0) {
                            areAllChildrenSelected = false;
                        };

                        if (options.term == '' || (child.text.toLowerCase().indexOf(options.term.toLowerCase()) >= 0)) {
                            anyChildMatchTerm = true;
                        }
                        else if (!parentMatchTerm) {
                            var index = group.children.indexOf(child);
                            if (index > -1) {
                                group.children.splice(index, 1);
                            };
                        };
                    };

                    return (!areAllChildrenSelected && (parentMatchTerm || anyChildMatchTerm)) ? group : null;
                });

                options.callback({ results: selectableGroups });
            }
        }).on('select2-selecting', function (e) {
            var $select = $(this);
            if (e.val == '') {
                e.preventDefault();
                $select.select2('data', $select.select2('data').concat(e.choice.children));
                $select.select2('close');
            }
        });
```

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/lmillar519/agkyvhnf/1/)